# Does debezium support capture postgres schema change event?

Tags: postgresql, debezium, change-data-capture

Does debezium support capture postgres schema change like 'alter table xxx add/drop/alter column xxx'?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-triggers.html

Answer (score 4):

Seems like an old question but in any way the short answer is yes. checkout the documentation here https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/postgresql.html .
With some exceptions:

> The PostgreSQL connector retrieves schema information as part of the events sent by the logical decoding plug-in. However, the connector does not retrieve information about which columns compose the primary key. The connector obtains this information from the JDBC metadata (side channel). If the primary key definition of a table changes (by adding, removing or renaming primary key columns), there is a tiny period of time when the primary key information from JDBC is not synchronized with the change event that the logical decoding plug-in generates. During this tiny period, a message could be created with an inconsistent key structure. To prevent this inconsistency, update primary key structures as follows:

> Put the database or an application into a read-only mode.
> Let Debezium process all remaining events.
> Stop Debezium.
> Update the primary key definition in the relevant table.
> Put the database or the application into read/write mode.
> Restart Debezium.